# ANDROID - service called by AlarmManager wont stop after destroy

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

i have a service getting started by Alarm Manager set to be repeated:

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
serviceSaveSample = new Intent(RunActivity.this,SaveSampleService.class);
alarmSaveSample = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 9988766, serviceSaveSample, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (secondsToSample*1000) , secondsToSample*1000, alarmSaveSample);
```

my onDestory function:

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
if(alarmSaveSample!=null)
alarm.cancel(alarmSaveSample);
if(alarmSendSample!=null)
alarm.cancel(alarmSendSample);

// stop services
if(serviceSendSample!=null)
stopService(serviceSendSample);
if(serviceSaveSample!=null)
stopService(serviceSaveSample);

super.onDestroy();
```

when i exit the app (by clearing it from memory in main screen) i get the error:

```
 10-31 13:58:32.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24267):
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service
 com.b2e.m2v.SaveSampleService@411b9ba8 with Intent { flg=0x4
 cmp=com.b2e.m2v/.SaveSampleService (has extras) }:
 java.lang.NullPointerException 10-31 13:58:32.800:
 E/AndroidRuntime(24267):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2801)
 10-31 13:58:32.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24267):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:153) 10-31
 13:58:32.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24267):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
 10-31 13:58:32.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24267):   at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-31
 13:58:32.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24267):     at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-31 13:58:32.800:
 E/AndroidRuntime(24267):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227) 10-31
 13:58:32.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24267):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-31
 13:58:32.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24267):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 10-31 13:58:32.800:
 E/AndroidRuntime(24267):   at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
 10-31 13:58:32.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24267):   at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562) 10-31
 13:58:32.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24267):     at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-31 13:58:32.800:
 E/AndroidRuntime(24267): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 10-31 13:58:32.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24267):   at
 com.b2e.m2v.Controller.getLocation(Controller.java:75) 10-31
 13:58:32.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24267):     at
 com.b2e.m2v.SaveSampleService.onStartCommand(SaveSampleService.java:35)
 10-31 13:58:32.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24267):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2784)
 10-31 13:58:32.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24267):   ... 10 more
```

any idea why ?

maybe its important to say that this code run inside FragmentActivity

Comment: what is the code in `Controller.java` in line 75?

Comment: @thepoosh does it matter ? its a static class

Comment: @thepoosh : public Location getLocation(){
  Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
  return location;
 }

Answer (score 3):

```
 public void SetAlarm(Context context)
     {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }     




 public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
         {
             Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
             PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
             AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
             alarmManager.cancel(sender);
         }
```

Comment: Yes i have passed.   this is my cancel method in service class public static void CancelAlarm() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, Favourite.class);
  PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent
    .getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  alarmManager.cancel(sender);
 } Services.CancelAlarm();  this is my activty class for calling cancel method

Comment: when u call this Services.CancelAlarm(); then pass context of that class bro with this like Services.CancelAlarm(context);

Comment: yes its working, thanks. but my service never stop its continuously running.

Comment: then try to stop that service dude and always welcome dude :)

Comment: in this ans user only ask for stop alarm actually :) just goggle about stop service dude :)

Answer (score 1):

as you can see from your stack trace, you're experiencing a `NullPointerException` in your `Controller` class.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(24267): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 13:58:32.800: E/AndroidRuntime(24267):   at com.b2e.m2v.Controller.getLocation(Controller.java:75)
```

this means that something went wrong there. from your comment I understand that that code looks a little like this:

```
public Location getLocation(){ 
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    return location;
}
```

this means that your variable `locationManager` is `null` when you're trying to get it.

Comment: that is the problem. the service still run in the background and therefore its calling a function that does not suppose to exist. and i want to stop the service (not keep it in background)

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

`alarmSaveSample = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 9988766, serviceSaveSample, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);`

to

`alarmSaveSample = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 9988766, serviceSaveSample, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);`

ie **Service** to **Broadcast**

For some reason, despite cancelling the former in about umpteen different positions it would, variably, keep reawakening the service indefinitely. YMMV